# SQL Server: query table filter by columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that I am trying to query. It has two fields that UNIQUE Ids. For this example, I am going to use PersonA, PersonB, PersonC, PersonD. The table represents a relationship between two people.

Person Relationship table:

```
Row     FieldId_01  FieldId_02 
------------------------------
1       PersonA     PersonB
2       PersonA     PersonC
3       PersonB     PersonA
4       PersonC     PersonA
5       PersonD     PersonA
```

`Person` table:

```
PersonID
---------
PersonA
PersonB
PersonC
PersonD
```

I don't care about the order, I just need the unique combination in reference to `PersonA`. So, row 1 and row 3 are the same, row 2 and 4 are the same, row 5 has no match, but still a unique combination.

I need to select a single unique combination.

Expected output should be

Person Relationship table

```
Row     FieldId_01  FieldId_02 
-------------------------------
1       PersonA     PersonB
2       PersonA     PersonC
5       PersonD     PersonA
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is... do you want to modify the Relationship table to only have unique rows? Or do you just want a query that factors in that reciprocal relationships are "the same" and eliminate those from the result set?

Comment: updated the post with my question

Comment: and it is still completely unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: One more clarification. You say you need the unique combination in reference to person A... but the example shows PersonA in every input row.  If there was an input row that related PersonB to PersonD, do you want that, since it's unique? Or are you implying that you want to filter for "all unique rows that involve PersonA"? In otherwords, if there was a row 6 with PersonB/PersonD... do you want Row 6 returned or not?

Comment: so basically a combination PersonA/PersonB and PersonB/PersonA is the same and related to PersonA. So in your example, PersonB/PersonD is not what I need because PersonA is not in either FieldID_01 or FieldID_02 (should of just said that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you are looking for. I included the sample data in a temp table so you can test it immediately:

```
CREATE TABLE #T (id int not null PRIMARY KEY, companyName varchar(16) not null)

INSERT INTO #t Values 
(1,       'dogs ltd'),
(2,       'cats ltd'),
(3,       'pigs ltd'),
(4,       'pigs ltd'),
(5,       'cats ltd'),
(6,       'cats ltd'),
(7,       'dogs ltd'),
(8,       'pigs ltd')

SELECT id, CompanyName
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        LEAD(CompanyName, 1) OVER(ORDER BY id) as nc,
        LAG(CompanyName, 1) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS pc
    FROM #t t
    ) x
WHERE nc = companyName
    OR pc = companyName
```

My Output:

```
id  CompanyName
3   pigs ltd
4   pigs ltd
5   cats ltd
6   cats ltd
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `not exists()`:

If `FieldId_01` is never the same as `FieldId_02` in the same row, then:

```
select *
from t
where not exists (
  select 1
  from t as i
  where i.Row < t.Row
    and i.FieldId_01 in (t.FieldId_01,t.FieldId_02)
    and i.FieldId_02 in (t.FieldId_01,t.FieldId_02)
  )
```

otherwise

```
select *
from t
where not exists (
  select 1
  from t as i
  where i.Row < t.Row
    and ( (i.FieldId_01 = t.FieldId_01 and i.FieldId_02 = t.FieldId_02)
      or  (i.FieldId_02 = t.FieldId_01 and i.FieldId_01 = t.FieldId_02)
       )
  )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/SQL61250

both return:

```
+-----+------------+------------+
| Row | FieldId_01 | FieldId_02 |
+-----+------------+------------+
|   1 | PersonA    | PersonB    |
|   2 | PersonA    | PersonC    |
|   5 | PersonD    | PersonA    |
+-----+------------+------------+
```